# JAVA : How do I input a ( < 0 ) to break the code?

Tags: java, while-loop, break

2 weeks in. I need to break the while loop with a negative integer but I've been unable to implement it successfully. This is my original code before I editted left and right to no avail. The values in Print are outside the loop.

```
public class AssignmentQuestion2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //write your code here

        ArrayList<Integer> rainfall = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input rainfall(Input negative value to exit)");
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                rainfall.add(in.nextInt()); //how to input into array

                System.out.println(calculateAverage(rainfall)); //average
                System.out.println(findSmallest(rainfall)); //smallest input
                System.out.println(findLargest(rainfall)); //largest input
            } else {
                in.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break a loop using the (aptly named) `break` statement:

```
    int r;
    while ((rainfall != null)) {
        if (in.hasNextInt()) {
            r = in.nextInt();
            if (r < 0) {
                 break;
            }

            rainfall.add(r); //how to input into array

            System.out.println(calculateAverage(rainfall)); //average
            System.out.println(findSmallest(rainfall)); //smallest input
            System.out.println(findLargest(rainfall)); //largest input
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I've another problem now though: The integer used to break is added into the array, and I need to prevent that. 

Edit - I've found the solution through T&E. Thank you again!